# Can't install xampp for linux

Tags: installation, command-line, apache2, lamp, su

I'm trying to install xampp as shown [here](http://www.apachefriends.org/it/xampp-linux.html#4474), with the following line:

```
su
chmod 755 xampp-linux-1.8.3-installer.run
./xampp-linux-1.8.3-installer.run
```

Su goes well, but the terminal doesn't run the other two lines and doesn't raise any error, so I can't understand how to fix it. I tried to go to `/opt/lampp` but that directory doesn't exists. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LAMP (**L**inux-**A**pache-**M**ysql-**P**HP) and you can install it from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Answer (score 1):

After you download `XAMPP`, usually the file is not executable yet, so we must make it executable with

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-1.8.3-installer.run
```

And then you can run it

```
./xampp-linux-1.8.3-installer.run
```